# Measure using memory of function in different languages

Tags: java, python, c, memory, pascal

I have a task who include measure a using memory (virtual or Ram or etc. [it must be same in all four languages]) of some code block.

For exemple using memory for Bubble Sort.

I using four languages:

- Java
- C
- Pascal
- Python

For Java I found a `runtime`class who measure a virtual memory.

For Python I found a `tracemalloc`class. In documentation i found that tracemalloc measure a allocate memory.

Can i compare `tracemalloc` results with `runtime` results?

Have you any advices how to measure using memory in C and Pascal?

Comment: If you are going to bubble sort 100 bytes, you need 102 bytes of memory (100 for the data, 2 for indexes).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option for Free Pascal Compiler is to [write your own memory manager](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu175.html) (in which you can simply trace and redirect calls to default MM).

In C you can write your own `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`, in C++ you can overload `new` and `delete` (see Effective C++ chapter 8 "Customizing new and delete"), but only for sources you control. Tracing in general case seems to be tricky. Choosing of optimal solution depends on how your project is organized, which compilers do you want to support, which build environment, what precision do you need etc.